# Display More Reports on One Report in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to show more than one report on a Page like Classic Report, Charts. how could i do this using iReport ? (i'm using iReport v 4.1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subreports. Your main report just consists of two or more subreports placed onto the page as you'd like them to be displayed.